# Async XML write is clearing file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, async-await

I am working on a class that creates or opens an xml file:

```
namespace QTabs
{
    public class DataLayer
    {
        XmlDocument XMLDocObject = new XmlDocument();
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile;
        string xmlFile = "DataStore.xml";
        public DataLayer()
        {
            loadXML();
        }

        public async void loadXML()
        {
            //if XML doc doesnt exist create it
            try
            {
                storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlFile);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                storageFile = null;
            }
            if (storageFile == null)
            {

                storageFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(xmlFile);
                // Manipulate the xml document.
                var root = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("SyncTimes");
                XMLDocObject.AppendChild(root);
                var childTag1 = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("id");
                var childTag2 = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("dateTime");
                root.AppendChild(childTag1);
                root.AppendChild(childTag2);
                await XMLDocObject.SaveToFileAsync(storageFile);
            }
            else
            {
                storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlFile);
            }
        }
        public async void addSyncTime()
        {
            XmlElement x1 = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("SyncTime");
            XmlElement x11 = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("id");
            x11.InnerText = "1";
            x1.AppendChild(x11);
            XmlElement x12 = XMLDocObject.CreateElement("dateTime");
            x12.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            x1.AppendChild(x12);
            await XMLDocObject.SaveToFileAsync(storageFile);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is with the above addSyncTime() method. When it runs it results in the XML file being empty, including removing the elements added on creation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. However, your code appears to have two different problems:

1. When the XML file is already present, you don't ever bother to actually *load* it, leaving `XMLDocObject` referencing an empty document. (Indeed, the `storageFile != null` case seems completely out of place; not only does it not load the XML from `storageFile` as I'd expect, it actually *re-retrieves* the `storageFile` object by calling `GetFileAsync()` again).
2. Your `addSyncTime()` method creates new elements, but never adds them to the XML document tree.

Given the above, I would expect the program behavior to be:

- The first time you run the program, the XML document is created.
- Any subsequent time you run the program (unless you delete the XML document), attempts to update the XML document will empty the document.

In neither case would I expect *new* `SyncTime` elements to be added. The first time you run the program, you'll get the root `SyncTimes` element and its initial `id` and `dateTime` children, but not any `SyncTime` elements. After that, the XML document will be emptied, and you'll still not get any new `SyncTime` elements.

If the above does not address your concern, please provide a good code example as described in the link I provide above.